# How to send email with inline image using ThymeLeaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I'm trying to send an email with an inline image using ThymeLeaf and Spring, but so far no success. The email sends, but the inline image won't show in the email.

The project is not web-based (not a website), but is a desktop stand-alone, not mobile

This is how I get the image file:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/LawFirmAdvisoryGroup.jpg");
File file = new File(url.getPath());

MultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile(file.getName(),
    file.getName(), "image/jpeg", IOUtils.toByteArray(input));
```

---

My service class:

```
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender mailSender;

@Autowired
private TemplateEngine templateEngine;

public void sendMailWithInline(final String recipientName, final String recipientEmail, final MultipartFile image, final byte[] imageBytes)
throws MessagingException {

    final Context ctx = new Context();
        ctx.setVariable("imageResourceName", image.getName()); // so that we can reference it from HTML

        final MimeMessage mimeMessage = this.mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        final MimeMessageHelper message
        = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");
        message.setSubject("Inline Image");
        message.setFrom("XXXX@yahoo.com");
        message.setTo(recipientEmail);

        // Add the inline image, referenced from the HTML code as "cid:${imageResourceName}"
        final InputStreamSource imageSource = new ByteArrayResource(imageBytes);
        message.addInline(image.getName(), imageSource, image.getContentType());


        final String htmlContent = this.templateEngine.process("left_sidebar.html", ctx);
        message.setText(htmlContent, true);
        this.mailSender.send(mimeMessage);

    }
```

---

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head>
    <title th:remove="all">Email with inline image</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <img src="LawFirmAdvisoryGroup.jpg" th:src="'cid:' + ${imageResourceName}" />
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "_so far no success_" You should really try to be more descriptive about what is happening rather than just saying "it doesn't work".

Comment: @Takendarkk I did edited the question. The email sends, but the inline image won't show in the email.

Comment: @Program-Me-Rev, Did you solve it?

Comment: @Program-Me-Rev is this problem solved by the  below solutions provided ? i am facing the same issue .

Comment: @Program-Me-Rev may i please know what is input ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works perfectly:

Just add a link to the image hosted on an external server away from your desktop. Use inline CSS, instead of CSS classes.

This website will help you convert CSS classes to inline CSS, [Premailer.Dialect](http://premailer.dialect.ca/).

Avoid any fancy CSS, just use the most basic. Floating (like float: left;) should be avoided as much as possible if you'd like your HTML mail to flow easily, even in mobile devises and other smaller screens.

Include [NekoHTML](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/) in your project libraries, and change your [Spring](https://spring.io/) spring.xml to:

```
<!-- THYMELEAF: Template Resolver for email templates -->
<bean id="emailTemplateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="resources/WEB_INF/HTMLMailTemplates/XXXX/html/" />
    <!-- <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" /> -->
    <property name="templateMode" value="LEGACYHTML5" />
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>
```

Sample this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Email With Inline Images</title>

    <style>
        body {
            background-image: url('https://dl.dropbox.com/s/XXXX/pageBackGround.gif');
            background-repeat: repeat;
            margin:0;
            outline:0;
        }
        .pageContentWrapper {
            padding:10px;
            width: 100%;
            background-image: url('https://dl.dropbox.com/s/XXXX/smallerInlineImage.gif');
            background-repeat: repeat;
        }
        .smallerInlineImage {
            width: 22px;
            height: 22px;
            padding: 0 4px 6px 0;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="pageContentWrapper">
        <div class="smallerInlineImage">
            <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/3ydel6zp53pb65b/smallerInlineImage.png" height="22" width="22">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Service Class:

```
@Service
public class ThymeEmailService {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    @Autowired
    private TemplateEngine templateEngine;

    public void sendMailWithInline() throws MessagingException {

        final Context ctx = new Context();

        final MimeMessage mimeMessage = this.mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        final MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");
        message.setSubject("Sample Email Subject");
        message.setFrom("senderEmail@yahoo.com");
        message.setTo("recipientEmail@yahoo.com");

        final String htmlContent = this.templateEngine.process("emailTemplate.html", ctx);
        message.setText(htmlContent, true);

        String[] attachments = {"C:\\Users\\MyPc\\Dropbox\\CV\\myPDFAttachment.pdf"};

        for (String attachment : attachments) {
            FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(attachment);
            message.addAttachment(file.getFilename(), file);
        }

        this.mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Just move your call to `setText()` up a few lines.

The javadoc for [`MimeMessageHelper.addInLine()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessageHelper.html#addInline-java.lang.String-org.springframework.core.io.Resource-) says:

> NOTE: Invoke `addInline` *after* [`setText(java.lang.String)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessageHelper.html#setText-java.lang.String-); else, mail readers might not be able to resolve inline references correctly.

Comment: can you please elaborate ? i have the same problem?

Comment: i created an utility class, where i was setting inline images before email construction, inline images were not working, i moved to the end and was working magically, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class EmailSenderService {

    private final JavaMailSender emailSender;

    private final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

    public void sendEmail (MailDto mailDto, String nameTemplate)  {

        MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();


        MimeMessageHelper helper;
        try {
            helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message,
                    MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_MIXED_RELATED,
                    StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name ());

            ClassPathResource attachment = new ClassPathResource("static/pdf/practice-react-programming.pdf");
            ClassPathResource image = new ClassPathResource("static/img/auth.png");

            helper.addAttachment("reactive-programming-book", attachment);

            helper.setTo(mailDto.mailTo()); 
            helper.setSubject(mailDto.subject());
            /*it is important to specify the same sender address that you have specified in application.yml*/
            helper.setFrom(mailDto.mailFrom());

            Context context = new Context();

            context.setVariables(mailDto.propertiesMail());

            String html = templateEngine.process(nameTemplate, context);
            helper.setText(html, true);
            
            /*This must be set after calling the method setText()*/
            helper.addInline("auth", image);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            log.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
          //  throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        emailSender.send(message);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Thymeleaf и Spring boot</title>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>

    <!-- use the font -->
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            font-size: 48px;
        }

        .circle {
            border-radius: 50%; 
            border: 5px solid #fff;
            box-shadow: 2px 1px 5px #999999;
        }

        p {
            font-size: 25px;
            font-family: Cambria;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<p th:text="${'Hello Dear ' + name}"></p>

<p th:if="${name.length() > 5}">
   you name ...
</p>
<p>
     <b>Authentication has being passed.</b>
    <span th:text="${#dates.format(#dates.createNow(), 'dd MMM yyyy HH:mm')}"></span>
</p>

<p>
    text...
</p>
<p>
    <!--for external images.-->
    <a href="https://kipmu.ru/wp-content/uploads/ksplshd-scaled.jpg">
        <img src="https://kipmu.ru/wp-content/uploads/ksplshd-scaled.jpg"
             alt="http://localhost.com"
             height="220"
             width="220"
             class="circle"/>
    </a>
</p>

<p>Attached images</p>
<p>
    <img src="cid:auth" alt="http://localhost.com"
    height="220"
    width="220"
    class="circle" />
</p>
<p>
    Regardless, <br/>
    <em th:text="${sign}"></em>
<p th:text="${location}"></p>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.13.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#mail