# Send an image in the mail using thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring, image, thymeleaf

In my application I would want to send emails using javamail. I use Thymeleaf so that I can send some data. When sending the email, I want the background to be an image.

To achieve this,  I added an `img` tag to the HTML code with a relative `src`, but when the email arrives in the target mailbox, the image does not open. I stored the image in a folder in the same directory as the html file.

What could be the problem? I did not add any attributes in java mail properties for image processing, should I? If so, what properties exactly?

Below you can find my HTML Thymeleaf template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>
    <p style="text-align:center;">
        <img src="image/valayev.jpg" 
             width="400" 
             height="400" class="center" 
             alt="should open">
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the result:

[image: Mailbox]

And this is my folder structure:

[image: Folders]

Comment: Please follow this question and its [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140262/how-to-send-email-with-inline-image-using-thymeleaf). Also this [example](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmail.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send email with inline image using ThymeLeaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140262/how-to-send-email-with-inline-image-using-thymeleaf)

Comment: there is another gap discussed